# LINQ IN where query

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I want to write `foreach` loop to get all files with specified extention from  external `txt` file. For example I have in file variable:
 `extensions = "jpg,tif,bmp,png"` or
 `extensions "jpg,tif"` and I want to only get this files.

So far I have something like this but I don`t know how to go on.

```
extensions = Extensions.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string sourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(extensions.)))
{
}
```

I don`t know how to get to every element in 'extensions' array. How can I solved that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Contains` and `System.IO.Path.GetExtension`:

```
string[] extensions =  {".jpg",".tif",".bmp",".png" };
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Where(s => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: remove `.` character from extensions items because extension will be `jpg` not `.jpg`

Comment: @tomassino: nope. If you look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx): _"Return Value: The extension of the specified path (**including the period "."**),"_

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I forgot about a dot.